# Error while saving JSP form: .lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.abc.bean.enqformbean.EnqBean.setEnqAllocation(I)V

Tags: oracle, hibernate, javabeans

Problem while saving a form data into Oracle Database.

first, the problem was:

```
 org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Null value was assigned to a  
property of primitive type setter of 
com.abc.bean.enqformbean.EnqBean.enqAllocation
```

In bean class the variable declared as `Integer enqAllocation`
and in setter and getter method, it was `int`.

Changed the setter and getter method of that variable to `Integer` and now I'm getting an error:

```
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
 com.abc.bean.enqformbean.EnqBean.setEnqAllocation(I)V
```

Don't know what this error mean. The class path is generated and restarted the server too. But getting the above error while saving the data. Could please anyone tell me what the above error mean?

**`EnqBean` class:**

```
private Integer enqAllocation;

public Integer getEnqAllocation() {
    return enqAllocation;
}

public void setEnqAllocation(Integer enqAllocation) {
    this.enqAllocation= enqAllocation;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error mean that a method with the signature

```
void setEnqAllocation(int);
```

is not found int class `com.abc.bean.enqformbean.EnqBean`